# How do I re-align Curve Rotation to World Origin

Tags: 3d-view, bezier-curves, object-mode

As you can see my curve origin is not aligned to the world origin.  How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm not sure what you mean. Have you tried `Ctrl+A` > *Rotation*? or share your blend file

Comment: since the curve doesn't have a Z dimension, it's very sus what's going on, I suspect it's parented to  something that is rotated. Not sure why the pivot point is tilted, maybe you have a custom orientation. You make the guesswork harder by not only not providing .blend but also redacting the screenshot.

Comment: Maybe you have some rotations in delta transform?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question guys, it was late and I was getting frustrated.  I didn't make a project file, sorry about that.  Basically my curve, which had no modifiers/contstraints/etc is tilted off world origin, and I was just wondering if there is a simple way to get it flat again (to X,Y), as if it had just been created at World Origin.  Considering all the rotations are already set to 0, I still don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: If you don't hae the project saved then you no longer have the problem?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady well I just created a workaround and moved on. But to deepen my understanding of how Blender works, I was hoping to find an answer.  I've encountered this kind of thing before and am never really sure how to address it.

Answer (score 1):

based on my understanding of your question, you probably want to set the Curve's origin to the 3D cursor. it's simple. right-click the curve, go down to "Set Origin" and choose "Origin To 3D cursor".
[image]

if you meant you wanna move the whole object, just press "Shift S" to open up the Snap Menu and choose "Selection to Cursor"
[image]

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Actually what I want to do, despite how confusing the question was (sorry!), is rotate the object to be back in alignment with global X,Y.  In other words, so it isn't tilted as it is currently.  But since the rotations are already set to 0.0, I don't know a precise way to do this.  I can simply rotate the object by eye, but I was just wondering if there is a way to do it precisely, so that it is perfectly aligned to World XYZ, at 000.